# Android Studio Update Problems

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-sdk-2.3

Android Studio updated to 3.0 and I'm having a lot of issues with my project. Currently there is an error at launch that I can't find a way to solve.

Here is error stack:

```
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Failed to process /Users/nikitagudkovs/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.auto.value/auto-value/1.5.2/1b94ab7ec707e2220a0d1a7517488d1843236345/auto-value-1.5.2.jar
Error:com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: Error while dexing autovalue/shaded/com/google$/common/collect/$ImmutableMap.class
Error:com.android.dx.cf.code.SimException: invalid opcode ba (invokedynamic requires --min-sdk-version >= 26)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForJivaDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:     com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveBuilderException: 
Failed to process /Users/nikitagudkovs/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.google.auto.value/auto-value/1.5.2/1b94ab7ec707e2220a0d1a7517488d1843236345/auto-value-1.5.2.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

try compileOnly "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5" and annotationProcessor "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5".
It should work with gradle 3.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Try `Build > Clean Project` and rebuild again.